# Thinkpad broke, I removed drive and trying to boot from the enclosed external drive using other computer

Tags: boot, grub2

so my lenovo thinkpad broke and I removed the drive. I have one 500gb drive, partinioned 50/50 with windows storage and bootable Ubuntu which I would switch from the other installed m2 drive that was windows 11. The windows 11 m2 drive (full partition boot) works fine, however when trying to boot from the Ubuntu containing drive i am stuck at grub.

I see that due to my gpt parition table, some common answers here were a bit different than my situation, so I'm trying to understand the best way that I can change the grub configuration to boot from the correct EFI. I've pasted the terminal output below, and I believe that hd4,gpt1 is the correct target, but I do not know how to update the configuration (nano command is not installed in grub)

The machine is an old macbook intel based, the only device I had on hand that I know can handle multiple OS boots. I also have a desktop PC and macbook air m1 that I tried to use, neither of which detected the drive much less was able to select it for boot target.
Im quite sure it was Ubuntu 20, small chance it is 22 lts

Here is the output -

`````
grub> ls (hd4.gpt1) /boot/ boot .sdi
grub> Is (hd4,gpt1) / efi/ boot/ System Volume Information/ $recycle.bin/ 
grub› Is (hd4 gpt1) /efi Microsoft/ Boot/ ubuntu/ 
grub> Is (hat.gpt1) /efl/ubuntu/ grubx69.efi shimx64.efi mmx64.efi boot×64.csu grub.cfg
grub› nano (hd4, gpt.1) /efi/ubuntu/grub
Possible files are:
grubx64.efi grub.cfg
grub› nano Cha4.gpt1)/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg
error: can't find command "nano
•
grub> ls (hd4,gpt1) /efi/ubuntu/ grubx64.ef1 shimx64.ef1 mnx64.ef1 baotx64.csu grub.cfg
grub› 1s (hd4, gpt1) /efi/ubuntu/ grubm64.efi shimx64.efi mmx64.ef1 bantx64.csu grub.cfg 
grub) Is (hd4, gpt1) / efl/ boot/ System Volume Information/ $recycle.bin/ 
grub> Is (hd4 gpt1) /efi/ Microsoft/ Boot/ ubuntu/ 
grub> Is (ha4, gpt1) /efi/Boat./ boot×64.ef1 LenovoßT.EFI License.txt ReadMe. tat fbx64.efi mmx64.efi 
grub>````
`````

Thank you for your help in advance!

edit: trying to clean up the code for readability